# Operator >= returns false when it actually true

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compare two coordinates. I found that my loop never stops because of this:

```
exit = ((p.x * sign_x) >= end_pos.x) && ((p.y * sign_y) >= end_pos.y);
cout<< p.x * sign_x << " >= " << end_pos.x
    << "=" << std::boolalpha << ((p.x * sign_x) >= end_pos.x)
    << " "
    << p.y * sign_y << " >= "<< end_pos.y
    << "=" << std::boolalpha << ((p.y * sign_y) >= end_pos.y)<<endl;
```

The `exit` variable never becomes `true`. In the console I see:

```
9435.6 >= 132.6=true 180 >= 180=false
```

How it can be?

All variables are `float`. Values are written above. Variables with `180` as value never change.

Comment: If they are floats/doubles, it can happen.

Comment: Isn't this about operator `>=`?

Comment: @DenisErmolin: The downvotes are probably because you haven't specified e.g. the types of your variables, nor example values for which this fails.  (In other words, you haven't provided a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)  Also, your question title doesn't match your question.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: when float x = 179.9999...test x >= 180...will be false...but cout will print x is 180...maybe it is not exactly 180.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided example values of `p.y` and `sign_y`, so it's difficult to tell for sure.

But the problem is almost certainly that `p.y * sign_y` is not exactly equal to `180`; however it will be rounded when you print it.

I suspect that if your print the value of `(p.y * sign_y) - end_pos.y`, the result will not be `0`.

Comment: Didnt know that operator << with cout rounds values.

Comment: @DenisErmolin: Yes, that's its default behaviour.  You can specify the precision using [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Answer (score 1):

> 180 >= 180=false

This is a standard floating point accuracy problem.  You should see it when you use a debugger, the actual value is probably something like 179.9999.  You solve it like this:

```
bool closeEnough = p.y * sign_y - end_pos.y >= -epsilon;
```

Where *epsilon* is a small value that is large enough to absorb floating point calculation errors.  The float type has only 6 significant digits so with a value around 180.0, epsilon should be at least 0.001f.  If that's not good enough then you need to use double instead of float, it has 15 significant digits.

Comment: you can use with cout, setprecision() from <iomanip> to get more exact result.

Comment: Meh, what's the point?  It doesn't actually solve the problem.  Using cout is no substitute for a real debugger anyway.

Comment: he wants to use cout to printing values. I'm not suggesting using std::cout instead of debbuger...only better way of using it ;d